# Make my second monitor independent

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

First of all, I searched the internet for two days but found nothing that helps. I connected another screen and I have two now, I want to make every monitor to have his own dock and etc, really make every monitor independent. I have Nvidia Graphics Card and I use Gnome as my DE.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should find (at least partial) solutions using Gnome-shell extensions

I'm using [Multiple Monitor Panels](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/323/multiple-monitor-panels/), other interresting features available in [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/)

Comment: None of them working for me.